# Using React's forwardRef inline or as a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing around with React-Bootstrap's `OverlayTrigger`, which requires the passed child component to be able to receive a `ref` (stated in the docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlaytrigger)

I have the following working code:

```js
const Acomponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Button {...props} ref={ref}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      key="right"
      placement="right"
      overlay={<Tooltip>Tooltip!!</Tooltip>}
    >
      <Acomponent>My component with a tooltip</Acomponent>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};
```

Is there a way I can use `forwardRef` inline or as a component in order to avoid all the boilerplate?

Something like:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      key="right"
      placement="right"
      overlay={<Tooltip>Tooltip!!</Tooltip>}
    >
      {
        forwardRef((props, ref) => {
          <Button {...props} ref={ref}>My component with a tooltip</Button>
        }
      }
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};
```

Or:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      key="right"
      placement="right"
      overlay={<Tooltip>Tooltip!!</Tooltip>}
    >
      <ForwardRefWrapper>
        <Button>My component with a tooltip</Button>
      </ForwardRefWrapper>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `AComponent` is just rendering a `Button` and nothing else, and `Button` already accepts a ref. If that's the case you have, you should be able to delete `AComponent` and just do this:

```
<OverlayTrigger
  key="right"
  placement="right"
  overlay={<Tooltip>Tooltip!!</Tooltip>}
>
  <Button>My component with a tooltip</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

But it's possible you simplified it to ask your question, and `AComponent` has to do more stuff than just that. In that case: no, there is no shorter option.

Your first example won't work because it will be creating a brand new component type every time `App` renders. Since the type keeps changing it must unmount and remount each time, wiping out any state in the process.

The second one doesn't work, because `ForwardRefWrapper` has the same problem that `OverlayTrigger` has: if you're just given a `children` prop with an element of a function component, there is no way to know which element inside that function component the ref is supposed to be passed to. No way, unless you write code to do so, which is what forwardRef is for.

Comment: Indeed, I just simplified my example code. I totally understand the first part of the reply (the inline forwardRef). About the second part (the ForwardRefWrapper), would it be possible to create such a component what would assume that the ref should be passed to the top level element in the children prop?

Comment: No, react does not have a way to tell it to assume the top level element receives the ref. Even if they did, that wouldn't work for all cases, because the top level element could be a fragment `<></>`, which cannot receive a ref.

Comment: One last question: if I didn't care about the state or re-rendering the inner component, would it be possible to make the inline forwardRef method work?

Comment: Calling forwardRef will create a component. You would need to turn that component into an element. Using JSX, you would do that by assigning the component to a variable -- say `const Acomponent = forwardRef(/*etc*/)` -- and then making a JSX tag with it: `<Acomponent />`. So, the same thing as doing it the right way, just in the wrong place. If you bypassed JSX and directly called React.createElement, you could pass in the component without first assigning it to a variable `React.createElement(forwardRef(/*etc*/), null)`.